# Easier way to get image in drawable using parameter?

Tags: java, android, image

I have hundreds of picture in my drawable folder, is there an easier way to get this pictures using an int parameter.

Currently all I can think of is creating a loop with if statements, by creating a `string = p + "i";`

How can I return the drawable picture?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you have string id for the drawable you can get drawable id with

```
String stringId = "p" + Integer.toString(i); 

context.getResources().getIdentifier(stringId, "drawable", context.getPackageName());
```

`context` depends from where you call above code. if you call it from activity, then activity is your context and you can omit `context` and just use

```
getResources().getIdentifier(stringId, "drawable", getPackageName());
```